# Make ad-hominem comments

Tags: latin

- Ne ressentez pas le besoin de commenter l'orthographe, la grammaire ou
  la mise en page de l'article.
- Ne faites pas de commentaires ad hominem.

Peut-on employer la locution latine *ad hominem* en français ?

Comment: Qu'il s'agisse de sentiments ou de choses plus simples comme la faim on n'est pas maître de ce que l'on ressent; on ne peut pas dire à quelqu'un par exemple « Ne ressentez pas la faim qui vous tenaille! », c'est de l'aberration; c'est la même chose pour les sentiments, les besoins; je trouve cette phrase aberrante. « Ne vous sentez pas le besoin de … », aurait cependant fait de la phrase une phrase correcte du point de vue sémantique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L’expression *ad hominem* [est recensée dans le TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ad%20hominem), dans lequel on spécifie qu’elle n’est utilisée **que** dans l’expression *argument ad hominem*, défini comme un argument retournant les mots d’une personne contre elle. Son usage est donc limité, et le **commentaire** ad hominem ne ferait pas partie du discours français habituel.

Même son de cloche chez le *Petit Robert*.

Je suppose que le ***commentaire ad hominem*** serait bien compris de ceux qui connaissent et comprennent la nature de l’***argument ad hominem***, mais il ne s’agit pas de l’association attendue de termes dans la langue française. Ce n’est pas froncièrement mauvais. Une utilisation en marge, mais assez rapprochée, de l’habituelle.

À placer une ou deux catégories au-dessus du compréhensible mais fort peu académique...

- La pile était connectée du mauvais côté, alors j'ai **vice-versé** les connexions et hop ! la lumière fut !

Answer (score 2):

Il y a confusion courante entre deux locutions latines figées du monde de la rhétorique : *argumentum **ad hominem*** et *argumentum **ad personam***.

— La première consiste à confondre un adversaire en lui **opposant ses propres paroles ou ses propres actes**. Pour citer Schopenhauer qui semble faire référence en matière de rhétorique : « Quand l’adversaire fait une affirmation, nous devons chercher à savoir si elle n’est pas d’une certaine façon, et ne serait-ce qu’en apparence, en contradiction avec quelque chose qu’il a dit ou admis auparavant, ou avec les principes d’une école ou d’une secte dont il a fait l’éloge, ou avec les actes des adeptes de cette secte, qu’ils soient sincères ou non, ou avec ses propres faits et gestes. Si par exemple il prend parti en faveur du suicide, il faut s’écrier aussitôt : "Pourquoi ne te pends-tu pas ?" Ou bien s’il affirme par exemple que Berlin est une ville désagréable, on s’écrie aussitôt : "Pourquoi ne prends-tu pas la première diligence ?" »

— La seconde **vise la personne même de l'interlocuteur** au travers de son environnement, de ses expériences, etc. Selon le même :« Si l’on s’aperçoit que l’adversaire est supérieur et que l’on ne va pas gagner, il faut tenir des propos désobligeants, blessants et grossiers. Être désobligeant, cela consiste à quitter l’objet de la querelle (puisqu’on a perdu la partie) pour passer à l’adversaire, et à l’attaquer d’une manière ou d’une autre dans ce qu’il est : on pourrait appeler cela argumentum ad personam pour faire la différence avec l’argumentum ad hominem. Ce dernier s’écarte de l’objet purement objectif pour s’attacher à ce que l’adversaire en a dit ou concédé. Mais quand on passe aux attaques personnelles, on délaisse complètement l’objet et on dirige ses attaques sur la personne de l’adversaire. On devient donc vexant, méchant, blessant, grossier. C’est un appel des facultés de l’esprit à celles du corps ou à l’animalité. Cette règle est très appréciée car chacun est capable de l’appliquer, et elle est donc souvent utilisée. La question se pose maintenant de savoir quelle parade peut être utilisée par l’adversaire. Car s’il procède de la même façon, on débouche sur une bagarre, un duel ou un procès en diffamation. »

On peut en déduire que la tournure française « commentaire *ad personam* » a du sens, à l'inverse d'un « commentaire *ad hominem* ».

Answer (score 2):

Pas dans son sens le plus usuel<sup>1</sup> aujourd'hui en langue anglaise qui se [résume](https://french.stackexchange.com/conduct) essentiellement en l'attaque sur la personnalité de l'interlocuteur, à toutes fins utiles l'*attaque personnelle*. C'est la sémantique de l'[*attaque*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attaque) (l'agression, l'action de porter des coups) et celle de l'apport de l'adjectif [*personnel*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/personnel) (adressé, relatif à la personne), sans aucune préposition, qui vient créer la direction, que ne sauraient rendre aussi clairement aujourd'hui cette locution latine en français, me semble-t-il.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> « The newer sense of "ad hominem," which suggests an attack on an opponent's character instead of his or her argument, appeared only in the last century, but it is the sense more often heard today. » ([Merriam-Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%20hominem))</sub>